# Saving list items into an XML document

Tags: c#, python, xml, list

I have an application written in C# that I need to convert to Python, since I have recently switched to Linux. It's a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language (Vocabulary). Nevertheless, when the application closes, it should save each item from the list into an XML document.

In C#, I would create a following method:

```
void SaveAll()
{

    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string vocabulary_path = path + "\\Vocabulary\\Words.xml";

    xDoc.Load(vocabulary_path);
    XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Words");
    xNode.RemoveAll();
    foreach (Word w in words)
    {
        XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Word");
        XmlNode xWord = xDoc.CreateElement("Word");
        XmlNode xExplanation = xDoc.CreateElement("Explanation");
        XmlNode xTranslation = xDoc.CreateElement("Translation");
        XmlNode xExamples = xDoc.CreateElement("Examples");

        xWord.InnerText = w.WordOrPhrase;
        xExplanation.InnerText = w.Explanation;
        xTranslation.InnerText = w.Translation;
        xExamples.InnerText = w.Examples;
        xTop.AppendChild(xWord);
        xTop.AppendChild(xExplanation);
        xTop.AppendChild(xTranslation);
        xTop.AppendChild(xExamples);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
    }

    xDoc.Save(vocabulary_path);
    Sync();

}
```

...but I'm having concerns with the validity of the code I wrote in Python. The problem is that the list elements are simply not saved. Also, I am getting:

> /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py
>   Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1553, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 140, in
>   add_item
>       self.save_all()   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 202, in
>   save_all
>       tree.append(xTop) AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'append'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

...when I execute add_item() function, which contains save_all() function in it.

```
def save_all(self):

    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
    vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

    for xNode in tree.findall('Words'):
        tree.remove(xNode)

    for w in self.words:
        xTop = ET.Element('Word')
        xWord = ET.Element('Word')
        xExplanation = ET.Element('Explanation')
        xTranslation = ET.Element('Translation')
        xExamples = ET.Element('Examples')

        xWord.text = w.wordorphrase
        xExplanation.text = w.explanation
        xTranslation.text = w.translation
        xExamples.text = w.example

        xTop.append(xWord)
        xTop.append(xExplanation)
        xTop.append(xTranslation)
        xTop.append(xExamples)

        tree.append(xTop)
```

What is Python's equivalent for `xDoc.Save(vocabulary_path)`?

What is Python's equivalent for `xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop)`

I'm using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save `ElementTree` to file by using [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method, so the equivalent to your C# `xDoc.Save(vocabulary_path)` would be :

```
tree.write(vocabulary_path)
```

Also, the following piece of code means appending `xTop` to the root element :

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
```

so the equivalent in Python would be :

```
tree.getroot().append(xTop)
```

Comment: I have added `tree.write(vocabulary)` but am getting no results. The items I have previously added are not showing up when program starts. Could you check the rest of the code? I'm sure I have made a bunch of mistakes. Please, it's very important to me.